# Change ,5 to 0,5 in Excel

Tags: excel, rounding

I have one column in sheet 1 in Excel in which my values are ",5" and one column in sheet 2 where my values are "0,5". They are both stated as General in Excel. To be consistent I would like to change ,5 to 0,5 or the other way around. I also tried to change this with CTRL + F replace, but does not change this either.

Someone familiar with this problem and knows how to solve it?

Regards

Comment: If the comma is your decimal separator, then, most likely, the `,5` entries are text and not numbers.  You may be able to convert them to numbers by selecting a blank cell; `Copy`; select the errant column; `Paste-Special Add`.  The formatting change should then occur.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot Ron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ron Rosfeld stated in the comments, by copying the column and by clicking paste special + Operations = Add the problem was solved.[image]